# docker compose not recognized when using sudo

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I've installed docker compose V2, and I can access it from the command line regularly:

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.2.2
```

I've also installed compose-switch according to the manual instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#compose-switch and it's working fine:

```
$ docker-compose version
Docker Compose version v2.2.2
```

But if I use sudo neither will work:

```
$ sudo docker compose version
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
$ sudo docker-compose version
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

`docker version` is the same with or without sudo:

Version:           20.10.12
API version:       1.41

So, how can I get docker compose working with sudo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had installed docker-compose under my user's home directory. I had to move the file *docker-compose* from *~/.docker/cli-plugins* to */usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins*

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
$ sudo mv /home/<username>/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

And now everything works as expected.

Comment: i followed the tutorial on [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-22-04) and ran into this issue

Answer (score 2):

The docker command you are running as your local user must be calling a different binary than what it calls when running as another user (i.e. root user).

When you invoke a command using sudo, it will by default use the root user shell environment which includes the `PATH` env variable.

I suspect you will see a different path output when running these two commands:

`type docker`

`sudo type docker`

Comment: Yeah, I'd installed the new docker-compose file under my user's home directory. I had to move it.